Simple AoC2024: Haskell Regex TDFA exposes odd Int -> source0 -> source0 type mismatch?
In attempting day 3, part 1, of the Advent Of Code 2024, I decided to do a little Haskell regex-ing, and came up with:
import Data.List
import Text.Regex.TDFA

puzzle_03_part1 :: String -> Int
puzzle_03_part1 s = 
    foldl' (+) 0 . map (\(x,y) -> x*y ) $ mull_pairs
  where
    regex = "mul\\(([[:digit:]]{1,3}),([[:digit:]]{1,3})\\)"
    find_mul_with_remainder :: String -> Maybe ((Int,Int),String)
    find_mul_with_remainder s' = let (_,_,after,digits) = ((s' =~ regex) :: (String,String,String,[String])) in if null digits then Nothing else Just ((read.head$digits, read.head.tail$digits),after)
    mull_pairs = unfoldr find_mul_with_remainder s

(using pretty much a bog standard stack version 2.15.7 project... there's a few other libraries but presumably nothing relevant here)
Which works fine.  I was initially weirded out by the apparent overloading on the return type of the =~ operator, but after reading the docs, I locked down which variant of the operator I wanted with the appropriate type annotation, thusly.
Trying the same trick with Part 2, I expanded that to:
matches :: String -> String -> (String,String,String,[String])
matches = (=~)

puzzle_03_part2 :: String -> Int
puzzle_03_part2 input = 
    foldl' (+) 0 . map (\[(x,y)] -> x*y ) . filter (not.null) $ mull_pairs
  where
    regex = "(mul\\(([[:digit:]]{1,3}),([[:digit:]]{1,3})\\))|(do\\(\\))|(don't\\(\\))" :: String
    match_maker s = matches s regex
    find_commands_with_remainder (b,s) = let (_,cmd,after,groups) = match_maker s in 
        match cmd groups
      where
        num1 = (-1)
        num2 = (-1)
        match ('d':'o':'(':_) _ = Just ([],(True,after))
        match ('d':'o':'n':_) _ = Just ([],(False,after))
        match ('m':'u':'l':_) [_,numStr1,numStr2,_,_] = Just (if b then [(read numStr1,read numStr2)] else [],(b,after))
        match _ _ = Nothing
    mull_pairs = unfoldr find_commands_with_remainder (True,input)

(I originally had the regex match embedded as before, but moved it out in this way because I was having type errors).
To me, this should make 'matches' fix the variable types such that I call the right version of =~ and get the right types out.
The error I get, however, is:
Puzzles.hs:112:26: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Couldn't match type: Int -> source0 -> source0
                     with: [Char]
      Expected: (Bool, String) -> Maybe ([(Int, Int)], (Bool, String))
        Actual: (Bool, String)
                -> Maybe ([(Int, Int)], (Bool, Int -> source0 -> source0))
    • In the first argument of ‘unfoldr’, namely
        ‘find_commands_with_remainder’
      In the expression:
        unfoldr find_commands_with_remainder (True, input)
      In an equation for ‘mull_pairs’:
          mull_pairs = unfoldr find_commands_with_remainder (True, input)
    |
112 |     mull_pairs = unfoldr find_commands_with_remainder (True,input)
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

the 'after' parameter that gets extracted from the regex engine should be a string.  In fact, it is, quite handily, just so in the part1 solution.
Moreover, I don't get any type errors in my declaration and definition of "matches" either, so, from a compilation point of view, I would expect the value being generated by matches to have the type signature (String,String,String,[String]), such that find_commands_with_remainder can parse that out via the "match" function.  "after" is the third field of that 4-tuple, should be a string, and should therefore suffice just fine for passing on as the next part of the string unfoldr processes.
I've managed to verify much of this working independently in GHCI... for example, pasting in this as a multiline sequence:
matches :: String -> String -> (String,String,String,[String])
matches = (=~)
regex = "(mul\\(([[:digit:]]{1,3}),([[:digit:]]{1,3})\\))|(do\\(\\))|(don't\\(\\))" :: String
match_maker s = matches s regex
s = "xmul(2,4)%&mul[3,7]!@^do_not_mul(5,5)+mul(32,64]then(mul(11,8)mul(8,5))"
(_,cmd,after,groups) = match_maker s

I can then test the types of cmd, after, and groups.  In particular, for 'after', I get the expected:
ghci> :t after
after :: String

Okay, I'm baffled.  Why is this little program not compiling, whereas the first one compiles fine?
To me it seems like, especially with the "matches" function, any internal type jiggery-pokery of the =~ operator should have been caught at that point, and not leaked out into the where clause of an internal function.

Your after isn't in scope; you're getting Text.Regex.TDFA.after, which has type Extract source => Int -> source -> source instead of the String you thought you were getting. Move the let-bound stuff into the where instead.

You are a rock star.  I can't believe I didn't see that.
I blame sleep deprivation for not connecting it to finding another binding of a different type by that name.
I just threaded 'after' from the let clause down into the match call, and, naturally, everything works.

@CodeWeaver No need to blame sleep deprivation, I didn't notice either! I bemusedly annotated half a dozen subexpressions' types without changing the error substantially before I clued in.
